# how to load image and pass to Layout using JSON Data?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, hashmap, simpleadapter

This is My code,I'm trying to pass the image to listview but i get error.
how can i pass image ? should i download it into local memory first and then send it listview ??

```
  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all, "GET", params);

    if(json == null)
        System.out.println("NULL");
    else{
    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
    Log.d("All Developers: ", json.toString());

    try {
        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
        int status = json.getInt(TAG_STATUS);

        if (status == 1) {
            // products found
            // Getting Array of Products
            developers = json.getJSONArray(TAG_all);

            // looping through All Products
            for (int i = 0; i < developers.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = developers.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id    = c.getString(TAG_UID);
                String name  = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_PATH);


                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_UID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                //map.put(TAG_IMAGE_PATH, image);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                developersList.add(map);
                //Iamge Download
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Data");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                    developersList,R.layout.list_data, new String[] { TAG_UID,
                            TAG_NAME,TAG_IMAGE_PATH},
                    new int[] { R.id.uid, R.id.name,R.id.image });
            // updating listview
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });

 }
   }
 }
```

Errors

03-30 13:34:03.475: E/BitmapFactory(22326): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: Please update and include details of the error so others can hep you

Comment: i have added errors above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to re-invent the wheel - assuming you have the url to the image you can use [nostra13 library for image loading](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) it'll do all the nasty staff for you (cache handling downloading\ saving thumbnail etc..) it also have an exmaple project you can look at to better unnderstand of how to use it.